# Obter dados de tags em XML

Tags: php, xml, parser

Tenho um XML com o seguinte formato:

```
<dados-cad>      
<nome>Wender</nome>
      <data>2805094</data>
      <code>311</code>
</dados-cad>
```

Como faço em PHP para eu pegar apenas o conteúdo que está dentro de cada *tags* acima.

Comment: Você já tem alguma coisa? Se publicar suas tentativas dá pra ajudar melhor.

Answer (score 6):

Pode utilizar a classe [`SimpleXml`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.simplexml.php) do php.

Segue um exemplo simples de como utilizar a classe.

```
<?php

    $xml = '<dados-cad><nome>Wender</nome><data>2805094</data><code>311</code></dados-cad>';

    $simpleXml = simplexml_load_string($xml);

    // Acessando os elementos
    
    echo $simpleXml->nome;
    echo $simpleXml->data;
```

Mais exemplos da utilização básica dessa classe [aqui](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/simplexml.examples-basic.php).

Answer (score -1):

Não conheço quase nada ainda de HTML/XML.

Alguém poderia ajudar a fazer este tipo de consulta acima usando C#?

Uso o Visual Studio 2017, estou montando um cadastro de clientes em windows-forms.

Desta vez, quando o xml há sub-níveis, tenho dificuldades de obter o conteúdo de do nivel mais alto/maior(não sei o termo).

O exemplo abaixo é referente a um webservic para consulta de cpf:

```
    <consulta>
      <status>1</status>
      <return>OK</return>
      <result>
        <numero_de_cpf>000.000.000-00</numero_de_cpf>
        <nome_da_pf>FULANO DE TAL</nome_da_pf>
        <data_nascimento>30/12/1981</data_nascimento>
        <situacao_cadastral>REGULAR</situacao_cadastral>
        <data_inscricao>05/05/2000</data_inscricao>
        <digito_verificador>00</digito_verificador>
        <comprovante_emitido>9F73.DBF8.4F85.7860</comprovante_emitido>
        <comprovante_emitido_data>12:21:27 às 29/08/2017</comprovante_emitido_data>
      </result>
    </consulta>
```

O que preciso é pegar o conteúdo da tag 'nome_da_pf' e jogá-lo em um windows-form.

Estou usando o código abaixo, porém sempre da algum erro de referência no posicionamento do xml.

```
    private void button1_validar_cpf_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string urlConsulta = "http://ws.umsitequalquer.com.br/cpf/?xml5&cpf=@cpf&data=@dt_nasc&token=12545269WrhPkfgDHe11972584";
        DataSet dsRetornaEndereco = new DataSet();
        dsRetornaEndereco.ReadXml(urlConsulta.Replace("@cpf", maskedTextBox1_cpf.Text));
        dsRetornaEndereco.ReadXml(urlConsulta.Replace("@dt_nasc", maskedTextBox1_dt_nasc.Text));
        string retorno = dsRetornaEndereco.Tables[0].Rows[0]["status"].ToString();
        if (retorno == "false")
        {
            MessageBox.Show(this, "CPF Inválido!", "Validação CPF", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }
        else
        {
            textBox1_nome.Text = dsRetornaEndereco.Tables[0].Rows[0]["nome_da_pf"].ToString();
        }
    }
```

Após digitar um cpf inválido, tudo certo, a aplicação retorna sem problemas a mensagem do cpf inválido, porém quando lanço um cpf válido, o Visual S. diz:

***Mensagem: Excessão Sem Tratatmento***

***System.ArgumentException: 'A coluna 'nome_da_pf' não pertence à tabela consulta.'***

Estou rachando a cabeça rsrsrs

Desde já agradeço a todos!

Vlw!

Comment: Você não pode postar perguntas em comentário de outra pergunta. Você tem que criar uma nova pergunta inserindo as tags corretamente.